# Grails and form input multiple

Tags: grails, image-uploading

I didn't find the part about this in the documentation, so I will be very happy if someone can help me =)

I have this form on my page to upload multiple pictures, using **multiple** for my input:

```
<g:uploadForm controller="photo" action="add" autocomplete="off"> 

    <label for="files">Files to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
    <g:submitButton name="add" class="save button medium" value="ADD" />

</g:uploadForm>
```

And now, I don't know how to "separate" files in my controller.

It is ok for one file, using request.getFile(..), but how can I handle the "multiple" property of my field ?

Thanks for reading,

Alexandre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this within your controller:

```
List fileList = request.getFiles('files') // 'files' is the name of the input
fileList.each { file ->
    println 'filename: ' + file.getOriginalFilename() 
}
```

`request.getFiles(<param>)` returns a list of [CommonsMultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) objects. You can use these objects to get the file names (like in the example) or the file content (`file.getInputStream()`)

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer, but this just for a record

`request.multiFileMap?.each { name, map ->
   //do the logic
}`